# Enviar String pelo SoftwareSerial

Tags: arduino

Olá

Eu tenho uma string e gostaria de enviar pela Serial. Mas esta dando erro e não esta compilando.

Meu codigo:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial swSer(2, 3);
String variavel = "Hello";

void setup() {

}

void loop() {

swSer.write(variavel);

}
```

Comment: Qual o erro está exibindo?

Comment: Ja resolvi, obrigado

Comment: @abduzeedo favor ajustar a sua pergunta, colocando a sua solução, para se alguém tiver o mesmo problema, já saiba como resolver.